# Is it possible for a callee to force its caller to return in python?

Tags: python, introspection

Is it possible for a callee to force its caller to return in python?
If so, is this a good approach? Doesn't it violate the *Explicit is better than implicit.* sentence of the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)?

Example:

```
import inspect

class C(object):
    def callee(self):
        print 'in callee'
        caller_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        caller = getattr(self, caller_name)
        # force caller to return
        # so that "in caller after callee" gets never printed

        caller.return() # ???

    def caller(self):
        print 'in caller before calle'
        self.callee()
        print 'in caller after callee'

c = C()

c.caller()

print 'resume'
```

Output:

```
in caller before callee
in callee
resume
```

Finally, thanks to @Andrew Jaffe's suggestion on *context managers* I resolved it with a simple decorator.

```
# In my real code this is not a global variable
REPORT_ERRORS = True

def error_decorator(func):
    """
    Returns Event instance with result of the
    decorated function, or caught exception.
    Or reraises that exception.
    """

    def wrap():
        error = None
        user = None

        try:
            user = func()
        except Exception as e:
            error = e
        finally:
            if REPORT_ERRORS:
                return Event(user, error)
            else:
                raise error 
    return wrap


@error_decorator
def login():

    response = fetch_some_service()

    if response.errors:
        # flow ends here
        raise BadResponseError

    user = parse_response(response)

    return user
```

Comment: Well, I'm working on a web request handler library and have a subclass specific `login()` method. Inside it I'm using the base class `self.finish(error=None)` method. If there is no error the `finish()` method gets called at the very end but if there is an error then it's called like this `self.finish(SomeError()); return`. I just was curious whether it is possible to exit the `login()` flow just by `self.finish(SomeError())`.

Comment: As to the readability. The `finish()` method should finish the login process in any case, but if you omit to `return` on error the flow would continue which is not desired.

Comment: Seems like the right place for a *context manager* using exceptions and the `with` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong in returning a value from the callee, to be read by caller and thus behave accordingly?

instead of

```
caller.return() # ???
```

write

```
return False
```

and in

```
def caller(self):
        print 'in caller before calle'

        rc = self.callee()
        if not rc:
             return
        print 'in caller after callee'
```

<strike>and off course you can raise exception and catch it in the callee and behave accordingly or simply less it fall through</strike>

*Duplicate of mgilson*

Reason I would argue for Return Value based check

1. `Explicit is better than implicit`
2. Callee should not control the Caller Behavior. Its a bad programming practice. Instead Callers should change its behavior based on callee's behavior.

Comment: +1, beat me to it. This is so much more clear. You don't expect a function to return without seeing it do so somewhere - the asker's idea would lead to making it incredibly hard to read the code.

Answer (score 4):

In a sense you can do this with exceptions ... Just raise an exception at the end of `callee` and don't handle it in `caller` ... Why exactly do you want to do this?  It seems like there's probably a better way to do whatever you're attempting ...

---

As far as creating a jump in the callee, it looks like that is impossible.  From the [Data Model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) section on Frame objects (emphasis is mine)

> f_lineno is the current line number of the frame — writing to this from within a trace function jumps to the given line **(only for the bottom-most frame)**. A debugger can implement a Jump command (aka Set Next Statement) by writing to f_lineno.

Comment: hmm. you are referring to 'throws'. ?

Comment: @Arpit: raising. In python you use the `raise` statement.

Comment: @Arpit -- No ... That's a generator specific thing which I never fully wrapped my head around (since to this point, I haven't needed it)

Comment: oh! that's a new ,a bit different way of return :P +1 for the idea.